# Copy top 3 values from data to another column

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro that can find top 3 values from my sample data between columns B to G, then copy and paste the value to another column in Column Q with the row it is from (within Column A and the row (Row A) it came from.

Eg.

```
   D1 D2 D3
                                              Seq RowA ColumnA
T1 10 20 30              After running macro:  T1  D3   30
T2 11 22  2                                    T2  D2   22
T3 2  3  10                                    T4  D3   21
T4 6 19  21         


Sub Top3() 
    Dim rng As Range 
    Dim i As Integer 
    Dim r As Integer 
    Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Copy 
    Range("Q2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
    Range("Q2").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlDescending 
    r = 5 
    For i = 1 To 3
        Cells(r, "R") = Cells(r + 1, "A") 
        Cells(r, "S") = Cells(r + 1, "A") 
        r = r + 1 
    Next 

    Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Clear 
    Range("C2").Activate 

End Sub
```

Comment: Please paste your current code into the question so that we can help you work out what isn't working.

Comment: Hi attached, but I think my macro is wrong @YowE3K

Comment: People are much more inclined to help if they see at least **some** effort on your part.  They understand that it may not be even close to correct, but it gives them something to build on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Target`: All the Cells in the list of values
- `Target` is a range that is 3 Columns x 4 Rows `Target.Address = $B$2:$D$5`
- `Target(1)` refers to the first cell
- `Target(Target.Cells.Count)` is the last cell
- `Target(x)` is bound by its Columns

  - `Target(4)` is the same as saying `Target.Cells(2, 1)`
- `Target(x)` is not bound by its Rows

  - The first column in `Target` is column B and the last row is 5.  The next cell outside of the `Target` range is column B row 6
  - `Target(Target.Cells.Count + 1).Address = $B$6`

With this information it we can create a 1 dimensional array of `Data` that indices and values match that of `Target`.  Using a 1D array makes it easy to reference cells in the `Target` range using built-in Excel WorksheetFunctions.

[image]

```
Sub GetTop3()
    Dim Data
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim index As Long, x As Long

    Set Target = Range("Offset(B1,1,0,Counta(B:B)-1,3)")
    ReDim Data(1 To Target.Cells.Count)

    For x = 1 To Target.Cells.Count
        Data(x) = Target(x)
    Next

    For x = 2 To 4
        index = WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(Data), Data, 0)
        With Target(index)
            Cells(x, "R") = Rows(.Row).Columns("A")
            Cells(x, "S") = Cells(1, .Column)
            Cells(x, "T") = .Value
        End With
        Data(index) = vbNullString
    Next

End Sub
```

This blog shows how to resize a range using the `Offset` WorksheetFunction:  [Advanced Excel Dynamic Named Ranges](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/advanced-dynamic-ranges.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I understand it better and also for your help!